# what is the requirements to charge android tab via USB cable?

Tags: usb, charging

I wanna charge my android tab ( not a prestigious brand ) via a USB cable connected with my laptop. I tried but it wont charge, Is there any requirements to do that?

Comment: I using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It's probably not getting enough amperage. Lots of tablets won't charge via a computer's USB port because the USB 2.0 spec only provides 500 mA of output. Many tablets require more than that. If that's the case for your tablet, then it's probably not possible.

Comment: When I use my phone as a GPS, sometimes my car charger won't even charge my phone. That is, it **is** charging, but the phone is using up more power than the charger gives. Your computer may be giving some charge to the tablet, or the tablet may detect there isn't enough current and decides not to try to pull any charge out of the computer.